# msxml3.dll: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, xslt, dll, msxml

I want to convert an XML file in HTML with the XSLT method in C++.
But when I try to compile my code, I get this error:

`msxml3.dll: No such file or directory`

Here is the moment when I call it:

`#import <msxml3.dll> named_guids`

I already tried to put the full path like this, but it doesn't work either...

`#import "C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll" named_guids`

And I get a loooot of errors like this

```
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:194: error: stray '\22' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:195: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:197: error: stray '\4' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:198: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:215: error: stray '`' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:221: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:224: error: stray '\240' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:225: error: stray '\236' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:226: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:229: error: stray '\200' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:230: error: stray '\22' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:231: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:234: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:238: error: stray '\22' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:239: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:252: error: stray '@' in program
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:253: warning: null character(s) ignored
C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll:6:255: error: stray '\300' in program
```

I'm actually using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) in Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions please ? @juanchopanza

Comment: A similar question: *[Error while compiling C++ code on Linux for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417697/)*. It also involves `#import` and a DLL file.