# Error while compiling C++ code on Linux for Windows

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to compile a C++ application for Windows on a Linux host with the following command:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o app.exe app.cpp`

But there is importing of the specific Windows library in the code:

```
#import "mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only    \
   high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")  \
   auto_rename
```

And I get this error:

```
app.cpp:26:9: fatal error: mscorlib.tlb: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to copy the file from Windows host and put it to a directory with the .cpp file, but that doesn't work ether. This is a piece of compiler output when I do this way:

```
mscorlib.tlb:1835:19: warning: null character(s) ignored
mscorlib.tlb:1835:21: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
mscorlib.tlb:1835:22: warning: null character(s) ignored
mscorlib.tlb:1835:24: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
mscorlib.tlb:1835:25: warning: null character(s) ignored
mscorlib.tlb:1835:29: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
```

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: There is no #import directive in C++ preprocessor

Comment: Use `#include<..>` instead!

Comment: How about `#import ".\mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only`! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Slava `#import` is [an extension supported by MSVC compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp). I imagine it's unlikely `mingw` supports it though.

Comment: I tried to use #include and got the same output with many errors. And with #import ".\mscorlib.tlb" I got "No such file or directory" error

Comment: *"#import directive (C++). ... Used to incorporate information from a type library. The content of the type library is converted into C++ classes, mostly describing the COM interfaces."*

Comment: Why don't you just use a virtual machine and compile natively for Windows? Cross compiling is often more trouble than it's worth (in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

`#import` and `mscorlib` are C++/.NET (a C++-derived language by Microsoft), **not** C++.

MinGW doesn’t and can’t support that (C++/NET is too different internally, despite of similar syntax). Try using Microsoft .NET Core. It is cross-platform and should have a C++/NET compiler.

Comment: Are you sure it is .NET-specific? Not just Windows/Microsoft-specific? A reference is *[#import directive (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=msvc-170)*. Do you have a reference to support the claim?

Comment: Yes, it is .NET-specific. While I might be wrong claiming that that’s C++/.NET specifically, `mscorlib` is a core .NET part.